# Angular AOT compilation error: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'

Tags: angular

My app works fine. I want to use AOT to speed up loading the app and I'm getting a compilation error with ngc and AOT settings due to checking the FormA

In typescript I have my form with a FormArray field:

```
  private buildForm() {
    this.taskForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      questions: this.formBuilder.array([
      ])
    }
  }
```

In template:

```
<h3 *ngIf="taskForm.get('questions').length < 1" >Render Decision</h3>
```

AOT compilation:

```
 node_modules/.bin/ngc -p src/tsconfig-aot.json
```

error:

```
my-component.component.ngfactory.ts:4530:59: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
```

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution to this issue by manually casting the result of the `.get()` to a `FormArray`.
It's described in the Github issue, but I'll repeat it here for good measure.

Provide a getter in your controller:

```
get formArray() {
  // Typecast, because: reasons
  // https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6099
  return <FormArray>this.form.get('formArray');
}
```

In your template, you now have access to the correct properties and methods of the `FormArray`.

e.g.:

```
[disabled]="formArray.length > 0 && formArray.at(formArray.length - 1).invalid"
```

Comment: See this for more info on casting in TypeScript: http://acdcjunior.github.io/typescript-cast-object-to-other-type-or-instanceof.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
<h3 *ngIf="taskForm.get('questions').controls.length < 1" >Render Decision</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks. It didn't like it though. myComponent.component.ngfactory.ts:4530:59: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.  BTW, I'm using Angular 4.0.0-rc.3  if that makes a difference.

Comment: That's actually incorrect;

FormArray should have a property `length`. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html#!#length-anchor